# Conditionals in django models arguments

Tags: django

quick question. Does anyone have any idea how to write conditionals in django models?

For example I have this code here:

```
class Trip(models.Model):

    tripName = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    tripLogo = models.ImageField(default='default_trip.jpg', upload_to='trip_pics')
```

So here default value is `'default_trip.jpg'`, but I'd like to write a conditional that `if tripName == "russian"` than `default=russia.jpg`. Maybe not change default, but another image will be initiated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this part of code helped me to solve my problem.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tripName = getattr(self, 'tripName')
    if tripName in tripImages:
        self.tripLogo = "{}.png".format(tripName.lower())
    else:
        self.tripLogo = "default_trip.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that can be done on the model level, it must be done in the controller (otherwise, this would break the MVC pattern).

Keep in mind that Django's ORM wrapper must turn your model class into a usable table in whatever the underlaying database engine is. This type of "conditional default" is not part of any database engine that I know of.

Comment: I was afraid of that so it seems I have to move this task to another level of my project. Thank you for the respond :)

Answer (score 0):

default arg can be a calable.

```
def contact_default():
    return {"email": "to1@example.com"}

contact_info = JSONField("ContactInfo", default=contact_default)
```

read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default)